# Reclaiming Social Security Money from EU when relocating?

Tags: eu, social-security, pension

As an Indian national residing in Spain for 6 years, I have been paying a lot towards Social Security (health, unemployment & pension). Now am deciding to resettle in India forgoing any future interests towards living in EU. Is there a way to reclaim a part  of the money (that towards pension) I have paid as social security ?

Are there ways for better tax reclamation as well ?

Comment: There is no EU “social security”. I am not sure what goes under that name in Spain (health insurance? retirement pensions? the whole welfare system?) but your question needs to be more focused.

Comment: You need to research how pension works in Spain. In USA, you need to work at least 10 years to be eligible, and only after certain age. Under 10 years of work or below age, you are not eligible to anything, unless complications like your death or disability. Spain might be similar.

Comment: "Seguridad Social" - that's the social security in Spain. Of course there is no EU wide single-window social security but typically the welfare schemes are transferable between countries.

Comment: I'm referring to the component of the salary (monthly) that goes for the welfare scheme (social coverage towards healthcare, unemployment etc., ) the terms may vary across EU countries but most EU people will know what am referring here.

Comment: I am an EU citizen, worked in several EU countries, know a little bit about various aspect of EU law and welfare systems and I most definitely didn't know quite what you were referring to. Now, why would you expect to get *any* money back for healthcare or unemployment payments? Not that it matters legally but you were protected against these risks for the time you lived in Spain. Old-age pensions are a little bit different. There might be a way to get out of the pension system or consolidate your pension rights but even there I am pretty sure you can't reclaim *all* the money you paid.

Comment: Obviously, I would like to get back only the component of the money that I have paid which goes towards longer term things like pension etc., which I sure won't be using. Not the one I have enjoyed the services of (like health insurance). And 'all' of that money needn't be reclaimed, naturally the maximum possible of it.

Comment: am talking about something like this : http://www.toytowngermany.com/wiki/Pension_refunds_on_leaving_Germany

Comment: @user17177 Fair enough, thanks for the precisions.

Comment: you can't probably get back money from healthcare or welfare payments because those are insurances that DID cover you during your time here. You pay the insurance hoping to never use it but it's still a service. 

The only thing that you haven't benefitted from, is the pension plan. 
There are ways to export the pension fund, sometimes even with taxation exemptions, but it's completely dependent on the country you're in and possible treaties they have with India. 

I can't help you but I suggest to start digging the internet, this sort of stuff is out there.

Answer (score 3):

As was noted, the retirement annuity pension is the only portion of the social security benefits that you may be able to claim. In order to determine whether you are entitled to cash out those contributions, you would need to contact the pension authorities:

[Instituto Nacional de Seguridad Social](http://www.seg-social.es/Internet_1/LaSeguridadSocial/Quienessomos/InstitutoNacionalde29413/index.htm)
Ministerio de Empleo y Seguridad Social
C/ Padre Damián, 4-6
ES - 28036 MADRID
 
Tel: +34 915 68 83 00

Spain and India do not have a bilateral social security agreement, and one would have to have contributed to the pension scheme for 15 years to qualify for an annuity pension or lump sum payout, and at a certain age. To understand the implications of early withdrawal (e.g., taxes, penalties), you may wish to seek expert advice on what applies to your situation.